# PL/SQL: Selecting certain column based on their ending

Tags: sql, plsql

Here's what I'm looking to do.

I need a proc that will take an IN param that is a table name and OUT a ref cursor with only 3 columns.

The columns I want are those that end with _NAME_EN, NAME_FR and _ID.

I tried something like this, but sometimes the wording doesn't match the table name.

```
procedure getcodetable(p_table in varchar2, p_refcursor out cur) is    

query_str           varchar2(1000);
substr_table    varchar2(200);
sometable           varchar2(200);

begin

  substr_table := substr(upper(p_table), 4); -- this should remove the CD_
  sometable := trim(trailing 'S' from substr_table); -- this should remove the S at the end

  query_str := 'select ' || sometable || '_id as id, ' || sometable || '_name_en as name_en, ' || sometable || '_name_fr as name_fr from ' || p_table;

  open p_refcursor for query_str;

end getcodetable;
```

For example, most tables name will be CD_SOME_TYPES and the columns I'm looking for SOME_TYPE_NAME_EN. But sometimes, it's more like SOME_TP_NAME_EN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why look for the table name in the column at all?  Would a table really have multiple columns ending in "NAME_EN" or "NAME_FR" that you would have to have logic capable of choosing from among them?  If not, you could simply:

```
SELECT column_name
INTO   l_name_en_col_name
FROM   dba_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = p_table_name
AND    column_name LIKE '%_NAME_EN' ESCAPE '\';
```

... with similar statements for your ID and NAME_FR columns.  And then...

```
query_str := 'select ' || l_id_col_name || ' as id, ' || l_name_en_col_name  || ' as name_en, ' || l_name_fr_col_name || ' as name_fr from ' || p_table;
```

As an aside, I would discourage you from this design.  It is better to have some sort of metadata telling you what the appropriate columns are in each table, rather than relying on a naming convention.

Comment: I get a "missing keyword" at the l_name_en_col_name

Comment: I was giving you an approach, not writing the whole thing for you.  You need to declare l_name_en_col_name in your PL/SQL block as a `VARCHAR2(30)`.  Then double check all the syntax.